# Using ng-repeat after $http call

Tags: ajax, angular, angularjs-directive

I'm learning Angular (1.6.6), so I'm hoping/assuming I'm missing something basic.

I'm populating a drop-down menu on ng-init, which is working as expected. I'm returning JSON from the DB, and console.log() shows me that the JSON is pulling through as expected.

I'm stuck with ng-repeat, trying to display the data in another `div`.

**My Controller**

```
app.controller('RandomTownCtrl', [

    '$scope', 
    '$http',

    function($scope, $http){

        window.MY_SCOPE = $scope;

        $scope.getAllRegions = function() {

            $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: '/all-regions'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                $scope.regions = response.data;

            }, function errorCallback(response) {

                console.log('error');

            });
        };

        $scope.getRandomTown = function() {

            var guidEntity = $scope.guidEntity; 

            if (typeof guidEntity === 'undefined') { return };

            $http({
                  method: 'GET',
                  url: '/region-name?region-guid=' + guidEntity              
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                $scope.randomTown = response.data; 

                console.log($scope.randomTown);

            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });

        };
    }
]);
```

**The Markup**

```
<div class="column col-sm-5 content-column">

        <form ng-controller= "RandomTownCtrl" ng-init="getAllRegions()" ng-submit="getRandomTown()">

            <h3>Generate Random Town</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <select name="nameEntity"
                        ng-model="guidEntity" 
                        ng-options="item.guidEntity as item.nameEntity for item in regions">

                    <option value="" ng-if="!guidEntity">Choose Region</option>
                </select>
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Generate!</button>
        </form>


    </div>

    <div class="column col-sm-5 content-column" id="output-column">

        <div class="header">            
            <h4>Region Name:</h4>
        </div>

        <div ng-controller='RandomTownCtrl'>
            <p ng-repeat="item in randomTown">
                {{ item.name_region }} 
            </p>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing $scope and self together, you need also ng-repeat needs an array not an object.

```
 $scope.randomTown = response.data;
```

Comment: Making those change doesn't solve the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Beginner Angular mistake: I didn't understand that the `ng-controller` directive created an isolate scope, and the output I was expecting wasn't happening because the data simply wasn't there in that `scope`.